# Grunt wildcard use issue

Tags: gruntjs

I am using the grunt plugin https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-legacssy to flatten/remove media queries for IE7&8.

This is working if I create a 1 to 1 relationship:

```
'shared/_assets/css/_modules/foo-legacy.css': 'shared/_assets/css/_modules/foo.css'
```

And It also works if i want to have a 1 to many:

```
'shared/_assets/css/_modules/_all.css': ['shared/_assets/css/_modules/*.css']
```

But what I really need (for reasons I wont go in to) is that grunt loops through all css files in a folder and appends '-legacy' to the file. I *dont* want to concat all files to one file.

So input is:

```
foo.css
bar.css
(etc)
```

And the desired file output is:

```
foo.css
foo-legacy.css
bar.css
bar-legacy.css
etc
```

(there are lots of files so I don't want to this this by hand 1 line at a time).

I cant work out how the wildcard would work in the destination part of the code.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. You can use the `ext` (extension) option to add a suffix to any file, but it'll need the longer syntax:

```
legacssy: {
    build: {
        expand: true,
        src: ['shared/_assets/css/_modules/*.css'],
        dest: 'shared/_assets/css/_modules/',
        ext: '-legacy.css',
        flatten: true
    }
}
```